# Inserir valor da função time no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Eu penso que o meu problema é simples, estou tentando inserir na base de dados através da função `time()` mas não insere valores.

Código

```
 $time = time();
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (user_id, estabelecimento_id, opiniao, data) 
              VALUES('".$_REQUEST['user_id']."', 
                     '".$_REQUEST['id_estabelecimento']."',
                     '".$_REQUEST['opiniao']."',
                     '".$time."' ");
```

Dessa forma não insere nada na base de dados, não sei o que pode estar a causar isso.

A coluna está com tipo bigint

Comment: a coluna `data` é de qual tipo no banco?

Comment: É do tipo bigint

Comment: deixe seu insert assim e veja o erro: `mysql_query('inser....') or die(mysql_error());`.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro trocar a coluna no banco para datetime ou timestamp e no seu código php usar

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Ao invés de

```
time();
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução bem mais elegante é trocar o tipo de dado da coluna data como timestamp e deixar como default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
ALTER TABLE posts MODIFY COLUMN data TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```